# How can I clear the kernel extension caches while using FileVault 2?

Tags: macos, startup, filevault, encryption, kernel-extensions

I have the same problem as this user, [Air + Lion : plug in USB, keyboard/pad stop working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52499/air-lion-plug-in-usb-keyboard-pad-stop-working) , where the built-in keyboard and trackpad on my MacBook Pro stop working (and drop out of the USB devices listed) periodically when I plug in a USB hard drive.

The solution provided was to boot into safe-mode and clear the kernel extension caches, however I use FileVault 2 full-disk encryption which seems to disable booting into safe-mode.

Is there any way to clear the kernel extension caches in OS X 10.9 Mavericks without disabling FileVault 2 to get to safe-mode? I really don't want to de-encrypt and later re-encrypt the entire 750GB drive.

Alternatively, can `kextcache` be safely run on a system that isn't booted into safe-mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holding down <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> at boot time, for a boot drive that's FileVault 2 encrypted, presents the password dialog, then continues into Safe Mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you can plug a FireWire or USB external drive (lest's name it `ext_disk`), I would suggest the following used receipe:

1. Make a clone of your FileVault disk (let's name it `FV2`) on `ext_disk` with [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com/download)
2. Boot from `ext_disk`
3. Open `Disk Utility` and unlock `FV2`
4. Open `Terminal` or an `xterm` window to enter the following commands:

   ```
   cd /Volumes/FV2/System/Library
   /usr/bin/sudo touch Extensions
   tail -f /var/log/system.log
   ```
5. Wait to see that `kextcache` is correctly upgraded on… `FV2` (you don't risk anything since `FV2` isn't bearing the cache in use by your running kernel) and terminate your `tail` with a <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, close your terminal window
6. Reboot from `FV2`
7. Check if all your misbehaving extensions are working correctly
8. Safely erase `ext_disk`